# How do I prevent apps from trying to gain permissions?

Tags: permissions

I downloaded an app for a restaurant I frequent to collect points. When I tell it to show the QR code to scan at the register, it switches to a screen in my Android Settings to "Modify system settings". Of course, this app should have no business changing my system settings, but I need to press Back twice to get out of the Settings app, and to the QR code.

I'm tempted to just copy the QR code offline, and import it in another app, but I want to prevent apps from asking for these permissions after I've already said no.

Comment: If the app opens it's settings page can can not change this behavior. The common way is to make a 1-star rating at Google Play for the app describing the problematic behavior and wait for the response.

Comment: Frankly for a restaurant app (which they probably outsourced to someone who writes one app as cheaply as possible and then does minimal customization for each business) my advice would be to delete it.